# Google Colab - Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, google-colaboratory

In my compagny, we all have Microsoft environment.

**Is there a way to interface Google Colab with a sharepoint like we can do with google Drive ?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If the file can be shared publicly, you can use wget.

```
!wget --content-disposition https://org.sharepoint.com/personal/user_org/folder/filename.ext?download=1
```

Notice that `?download=1` is added to replace the `?xxxxxxxx` from the normal shared URL.

If you cannot share publicly, I am not sure, but maybe some sharepoint API can be used.